# github code search based on specific repo state (commit, tag, release)

Tags: github, search

Is it possible to use the github api to achieve code searches for a specific repo state (commit, tag, or release)? I can't find these kinds of parameters in the code search documentation.

Answer (score 1):

### Repositories API

Repos API allows you to create, manage and control the workflow of public and private GitHub repositories.
[docs.github.com/en/rest/repos](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos)

List repository tags: [docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repository-tags](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repository-tags)

### Watching API

The Watching API lets users subscribe to notifications for activity in a repository.  [docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/watching](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/watching)

### Commits API

The Commits API allows you to list, view, and compare commits in a repository. You can also interact with commit comments and commit statuses.  [docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits)

### List repository events

[docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/events#list-repository-events](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/events#list-repository-events)
See "Example Response" as well as "Response Schema"